# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at []

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I'm new in java cucumber.

When run runTest fail:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at []

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

java class:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}) 

public class runTest { }
```

feature file:

```
Feature: annotation
"#"This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
```

Background:
  User navigates to Facebook Given
  I am on Facebook login page

"#"Scenario with AND
  Scenario:
    When I enter username as "TOM"
    And I enter password as "JERRY"
    Then Login should fail

"#"Scenario with BUT
  Scenario:
    When I enter username as "TOM"
    And I enter password as "JERRY"
    Then Login should fail
    But Relogin option should be available

Comment: Feature file should be in class path

Comment: tried to clean up code as best I could

Answer (score 2):

Please check:

If all the feature files are present under

> src/test/resources

In Java class, Please add feature path as well to read the feature file.

@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},

> features = {"src/test/resource"}

)